# How to hide or remove piping errors (from the PHP command, from the output and from piping configuration)?

Tags: exim

I have a piping in aliases Exim file.
It's working fine, but when the script fails for some reason Exim returns all that information to user.

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  pipe to |/usr/bin/php -q /path_to_my_script
    generated by piping@mydomain.com
    (ultimately generated from sendhere@mydomain.com)
    local delivery failed

(and here appears all the PHP errors)
```

1. I have in PHP configuration to not display_errors, also a "error_reporting(0);" in the script, and also a "try/catch" to returns only what I want. But Exim, maybe because it runs PHP in other environment, I don't know why but it shows all errors of the PHP showing pieces of code. No clues about this. The only thing I did for solving this is to remove "return_output" in the address_pipe section:

from this

```
address_pipe:
  driver = pipe
  return_output
```

to this

```
address_pipe:
  driver = pipe
```

But I'd like to know how to avoid Exim to show PHP errors when it pipes to that command.

2. How can I remove that "pipe" information of the error email ? I don't want users to have the path of the script, and information about piping
3. Above all, how can I custom the error message so I can put a more friendly message ?

Thank you !